# Restrict Teamcity Shared Account

Tags: security, teamcity

It was talked developers several times not to use shared account while starting/stopping builds etc. hence "Shared Account" is usually guilty of broken builds :)

How could I restrict shared account to make any activity on TC except view build results?
It is assential to left shared account (unregistered user) to view TC build results to be able to share any TC build result/artifacts with anybody.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeamCity provides fine-grained [roles and permissions](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Role+and+Permission).  It has a built-in role, `Project Viewer`, that fits your need.  To assign this role to the `Shared Account`:

1. Browse to *Administration* -> *Users*
2. View the `Shared Account` user
3. Remove that user's existing roles and assign it the 'Project Viewer` role.

You can assign this role globally (to all projects) or to a subset of projects.  If the `Shared Account` is a member of any groups, it may have inherited roles from them.  In that case you may have to alter those memberships or the roles that they entail.